Julia Pkg.build not recompiling package
I downloaded a package from github and made some small changes to the source code. After saving the source code, I run the following in my terminal
>julia
>using Pkg
>Pkg.build("package")

This however does nothing. The package is not built and it is almost as if I made no changes to the original file. Does anyone know how i can force a recompile?

Was the package that you downloaded really called "package" ?

I ended up just deleting .julia directory and reinstalling Julia. everything works now. No clue what was broken.
